# jVectorMap - How to reload/reset the map or just change the hover/active color states?

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I have a page with multiple maps on it, each map will display different region data when clicked and have different region colors.

No I've accomplished all this: I can switch maps, which will load a different data set, and change the INACTIVE region color, but I cant figure out how to change the hover color or the active color.

Right now Im changing the inactive color with:

```
$.each(stateMap.regionCodes, function(i, val) {
  fill[i] = newFillColor;
});
stateMap.series.regions[0].setValues(fill);
```

But I cant find a way to change the color of the selected/hovered regions.

If there isnt a way to do that on the fly, can I destroy and reset map using the new colors?

Answer (score 0):

Use the params object of the map: `mapObj.params.regionStyle.hover.fill = "red"`, `mapObj.params.regionStyle.selected.fill = "blue"`.

You could also build a custom `myRegionStyle` settings object:

```
{
  initial: {
    fill: 'white',
    "fill-opacity": 1,
    stroke: 'none',
    "stroke-width": 0,
    "stroke-opacity": 1
  },
  hover: {
    "fill-opacity": 0.8
  },
  selected: {
    fill: 'yellow'
  },
  selectedHover: {
  }
}
```

and then do `mapObj.regionStyle = myregionStyle`

Take a look at the documentation: http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api-v1/jvm-worldmap/